# Empty Map Pattern matches even for non-empty Map

Tags: erlang

The problem I am trying to solve states

> Write a function map_search_pred(Map, Pred) that returns the first
>   element {Key,Value} in the map for which Pred(Key, Value) is true.

My attempt looks like

```
map_search_pred(#{}, _)     -> {};
map_search_pred(Map, Pred)  ->
  [H|_] = [{Key, Value} || {Key, Value} <- maps:to_list(Map), Pred(Key, Value) =:= true],
  H.
```

When I run this, I see output as

```
1> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 1, 2 => 3}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{}
2> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 1, 2 => 3}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{}
3> maps:size(#{}).
0
4>
```

**How am I so sure?** 
I pulled out the first clause so it looks like

```
map_search_pred(Map, Pred)  ->
  [H|_] = [{Key, Value} || {Key, Value} <- maps:to_list(Map), Pred(Key, Value) =:= true],
  H.
```

and run again

```
1> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 1, 2 => 3}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{1,1}
2> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value []
     in function  lib_misc:map_search_pred/2 (/Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/erlang/programmingErlang/src/lib_misc.erl, line 42)
3>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [map documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79794):

> Matching an expression against an empty map literal will match its type but no variables will be bound:
>
> #{} = Expr
>
> This expression will match if the expression Expr is of type map, otherwise it will fail with an exception badmatch.

However [erlang:map_size](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#map_size-1) can be used instead:

```
map_search_pred(Map, _) when map_size(Map) == 0 ->
  {};
map_search_pred(Map, Pred) ->
  [H|_] = [{Key, Value} || {Key, Value} <- maps:to_list(Map), Pred(Key, Value) =:= true],
  H.
```

Comment: This is much better and elegant solution. A new thing I learnt is `[]` is `empty list` but `#{}` is not `empty map`.

Comment: @daydreamer That's not true in general, it only holds if those literals are used as patterns.

Comment: Is there any difference between erlang:map_size/1 and maps:size/1? The first one seems to be allowed in guard expressions but the second one doesn't mention anything about guards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
map_search_pred(Map, _) when Map == #{}     -> {};
```

Note that Map =:= #{} won't work as it again matches when Map of type map. Better to use map_size(Map) sure. Just a nice, not obvious fact.